# Dúvida Query SQL - Consulta utilizando duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

estou com dúvidas em como fazer uma query. O problema é o seguinte:

- Tenho duas tabelas semelhante as descritas abaixo (não tenho exatamente como elas eram, mas são próximas a representação abaixo):

*Tabela 1 - Países*

```
| País  | Empresa  |

|País A| Empresa 1|

|País A| Empresa 2|

|País A| Empresa 3|

|País B| Empresa 4|

|País B| Empresa 5|

|País C| Empresa 6|
```

*Tabela 2 - Vendas*

```
| Código | Vendedor | Comprador | Valor |

| 1      | Empresa 1| Empresa 5 | 100   |

| 2      | Empresa 1| Empresa 4 | 20    |

| 3      | Empresa 6| Empresa 2 | 120   |

| 4      | Empresa 5| Empresa 6 | 10    |

| 5      | Empresa 6| Empresa 1 | 200   |

| 6      | Empresa 4| Empresa 2 | 60    |
```

Na tabela 1 não há primary key. Na tabela 2 a coluna "código" é primary key. Todas as colunas das tabelas são varchar, exceto as colunas "código" e "valor".

O resultado deve ser uma tabela com os valores de compra e venda de cada país. Do tipo abaixo:

**Tabela 3 - Resultado**

```
| País | Vendas | Compras |

| País A | 120 | 280 |

| País B | 70 | 120 |

| País C | 220 | 10 |
```

Tentei escrever uma query que chegue a esse resultado, mas não consegui. Nas querys que fiz, o mais próximo que consegui foi a lista dos países, mas a soma não estava correta. Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema? Por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente o seu problema, você precisaria fazer duas consultas para chegar neste resultado. A primeira consulta seria para montar a lista de empresas+pais  com as compras e vendas. Ficaria assim:

```
select P.Pais, P.Empresa,
(Select sum(valor) from Vendas where vendedor = P.Empresa) as vendas,
(Select sum(valor) from Vendas where comprador = P.Empresa) as compras
from Paises as P
GROUP BY P.Pais, P.Empresa
```

Sobre este resultado, você poderia fazer o agrupamento para montar a tabela por pais. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
Select Pais, sum(vendas) as vendas, sum(compras) as compras
from (
select P.Pais, P.Empresa,
(Select sum(valor) from Vendas where vendedor = P.Empresa) as vendas,
(Select sum(valor) from Vendas where comprador = P.Empresa) as compras
from Paises as P
GROUP BY P.Pais, P.Empresa
) tabela
GROUP BY Pais
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma que você tem de fazer é realizar `subqueries` para calcular a compra e a venda e depois utilizar um `GROUP` em conjunto com o `SUM` no resultado:

```
SELECT x.pais,
       SUM(x.vendas) AS vendas,
       SUM(x.compras) AS compras
FROM (
  SELECT p.pais,
         (SELECT SUM(v.valor)
            FROM vendas v
           WHERE v.vendedor = p.empresa) AS vendas,
         (SELECT SUM(v.valor)
            FROM vendas v
           WHERE v.comprador = p.empresa) AS compras
    FROM paises p
) x
GROUP BY x.pais;
```

Uma outra forma é realizar um `CROSS JOIN` e utilizar um `CASE` para verificar se naquela venda em questão há vinculo com o país:

```
SELECT p.pais,
       SUM(CASE v.vendedor WHEN p.empresa THEN v.valor ELSE 0 END) AS vendas,
       SUM(CASE v.comprador WHEN p.empresa THEN v.valor ELSE 0 END) AS compras
  FROM paises p
 CROSS JOIN vendas v
GROUP BY p.pais;
```

E há ainda uma terceira forma. Você pode realizar `LEFT JOIN` com a tabela `vendas` vinculando pelo `vendedor` e também pelo `comprador` e assim agrupar as informações somando com `SUM`:

```
SELECT p.pais,
       SUM(v1.valor) AS vendas,
       SUM(v2.valor) AS compras
  FROM paises p
  LEFT JOIN vendas v1 ON v1.vendedor = p.empresa
  LEFT JOIN vendas v2 ON v2.comprador = p.empresa
 GROUP BY p.pais
```

É necessário verificar o plano de execução para conferir qual a solução que custa menos para o banco de dados e que se aplica melhor ao seu cenário.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma sub consulta utilizado para saber os valores de compra e venda por pais/empresa, e depois agrupar por pais.

```
select 
    t.pais, sum(t.vendas) vendas, sum(t.compras) compras
from  (

    select 
        p.pais pais, 
        p.empresa empresa,
        (select sum(v.valor) from vendas v where v.vendedor = p.empresa ) vendas,
        (select sum(c.valor) from vendas c where c.comprador = p.empresa ) compras
    from paises p 
) t
group by t.pais
```

Veja um exemplo aqui: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8buC9rz8gXQtUCX8kw9jPV/3

Comment: Mas sua solução é idêntica ao que eu sugeri 5 minutos antes...

Comment: perdão amigo, nem tinha visualizado a sua solução, estava criando o exemplo no fiddle